# Sarebbe corretto sostituire "contractor" con "lavoratori" in questa frase?

Tags: word-usage, english-comparison

A volte mi risulta sorprendente l'uso di vocaboli di origine inglese che se ne fa in testi italiani. Frequentemente mi chiedo se non sia possibile in tali casi usare dei termini più italiani. Nelle notizie di Euronews ho letto questa frase (il corsivo è mio):

> Tra le vittime ci sono tre *contractor* della Nato, ha confermato il portavoce dell’Alleanza Atlantica in Afghanistan.

La mia domanda è: sarebbe giusto riscrivere questa frase in questo modo?

> Tra le vittime ci sono tre *lavoratori* della Nato, ha confermato il portavoce dell’Alleanza Atlantica in Afghanistan.

O forse così si perda qualche sfumatura (che io non riesco a cogliere)?

**Aggiornamento:**

Se il modo in cui ho riscritto la frase non è corretto o non è il più adatto, esiste alcuna espressione alternativa a *contractor* più italiana?

Comment: *Contractor* non è precisamente *lavoratore*.

Comment: Sull'abuso dei termini inglesi nella lingua italiana : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233187/an-appropriate-term-for-the-contamination-of-a-language

Comment: Scusa, @Josh61. Potresti aggiungere alla risposta la tua proposta di alternativa alla frase originale?

Comment: La traduzione italiana corretta di contractor in questo contesto sarebbe mercenari anche se non è politically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Un [contractor](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Inglese/C/contractor.shtml) è un'impresa o un imprenditore che lavora per conto terzi:

> - (Comm) appaltatore m. (f. -trice), imprenditore m. (f. -trice), impresario m. (f. -a).

L'articolo probabilmente si riferisce a persone che lavoravano in nome e per conto della NATO. Il termine *lavoratori* è troppo generico per definire un contractor. Un lavoratore potrebbe essere un dipendente della NATO, mentre  un  contractor no.

Una possibile alternativa in italiano ;

- "tra le vittime ci sono tre (lavoratori) terzisti della NATO".

Comment: Quindi si potrebbe dire *... ci sono tre persone che lavoravano per la Nato, ...*?

Comment: @Charo direi di no: "che lavorano" non esclude che siano dei dipendenti (anzi io tenderei a interpretarla come se fossero dei dipendenti diretti della NATO)

Answer (score 1):

I contractors che accompagnano i trasporti terrestri all'interno (per esempio) dell'Iraq e dell'Afghanistan durante i periodi di guerra sono dipendenti armati di società private che offrono servizi di sicurezza. La loro presenza normalmente è prevista da particolari condizioni di assicurazione del trasporto che si chiamano "warranties". Sono condizioni davvero molto particolari: se non vengono rispettate, gli assicuratori possono dichiarare la polizza non valida dall'inizio. Per farla breve: senza contractors non si assicura alcun trasporto in zona di guerra. I rischi che si possono assicurare in casi di guerra sono un'altra storia.

Answer (score 0):

Secondo me, dato che ogni lingua ha termini che *convenzionalmente* descrivono in una singola parola un concetto che in altre lingue richiederebbe una frase intera, una volta che il concetto espresso da quel termine diventa di uso comune, si può prendere in considerazione l'opzione di lasciarlo nella sua lingua originaria.
Per esempio se io fossi francese lascerei "computer" invece di tradurlo, "ordinateur", e personalmente sono lieto che in Italia diciamo "accendo il computer" invece di "accendo l'elaboratore".

Secondo me dipende tutto da quanto il termine diventa di uso frequente.

Non saprei dire se "contractor" è già di uso abbastanza frequente, immagino sia questione di opinioni e soprattutto di contesto. Se no, "terzista" come suggerito da @Josh61 sembra anche a me la traduzione migliore.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente in zone di guerra con il termine "contractor" si definiscono quegli operatori di sicurezza normalmente dipendenti di aziende private che operano più o meno in parallelo rispetto ai corpi ufficiali (polizia o esercito locale/transnazionale), che vigilano su strutture o altre risorse strategiche (incluse persone).

Ad esempio una grande azienda in una zona "calda" potrebbe assumere un corpo di contractor per coadiuvare la polizia locale.

Se proprio si vuole tradurre il termine "contractor" in questo caso (seppur ormai in uso anche in italiano), lo tradurrei forse con "Tra le vittime ci sono tre guardie di sicurezza della Nato, ha confermato il portavoce dell’Alleanza Atlantica in Afghanistan."